# Transform attribute in yaml.dump is not working

Tags: python-3.x, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

If we want to alter the output of yaml.dump we can use tranform keyword argument.
Documentation: https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html

Here is the yaml data:

```
metadata:
  name: name
  alias: alias
```

it is stored in variable x.

```
x = 'metadata:\n  name: name\n  alias: alias\n'

def tr(s):
    return s.replace('\n', '\n    ')  # Want 4 space at each new line

from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.compat import StringIO

yaml = YAML(typ="safe")
yaml.default_flow_style = False
stream = StringIO()

obj = yaml.load(x)
yaml.dump(obj, stream, transform=tr)
print(stream.getvalue())
```

On running above python script, Got this error:
**TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

Expected output:

```
    metadata:
      name: name
      alias: alias
```

Note: Another 4 spaces are added in each line

Version Details of setup:

```
Python: 3.7
ruamel.yaml: 0.15.88
```

Comment: IIRC that is because you experience a bug that has long been fixed. Any specific reason you use that old version of ruamel.yaml?  With version 0.16.10 and Python 3.8 I get the expected output: `"metadata:\\n  name: name\\n  alias: alias\\n"\n    ` (i.e. your original string data followed by newline and four spaces)

Comment: I do hope you realise you are not dumping a data structure, but only a single string with embedded newlines. If you want a data structure you should do `x = yaml.load(x)` first.

Comment: @Anthon updated the question , yeah forgot to add load line to code.

Comment: @Anthon, also if I see the version logs of `ruamel.yaml`. This issue that I found is not related to version at all. I see some changes in `0.15.4` and `0.15.35`. And I am already using a version above than that.

Comment: @Anthon, I also tried the combination of python 3.7 and ruamel.yaml==0.16.10. Still getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem only happens with `StringIO`, because `YAML()` always sets the encoding to `utf-8` (and `allow_unicode = True`).

Changing to use `io` didn't help. If you want to write to `StringIO` in python2.7 you'll have to disable the utf-8 encoding:

i.e.

```py
yaml = YAML(typ="safe")
yaml.default_flow_style = False
stream = StringIO()
yaml.encoding = None
```

For more info see this ticket : https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/tickets/271/