# YAML find and replace text Python

Tags: python, yaml

I have some files in YAML format, I need to find the text in the **$title** file and replace with what I specified. What the configuration file looks like approximately:

```
JoinGame-MOTD:
  Enabled: true
  Messages:
  - '$title'
```

The YAML file may look different, so I want to make a universal code that will not get any specific string, but replace all **$title** with what I specified

What I was trying to do:

```
import sys
import yaml

with open(r'config.yml', 'w') as file:
    
    def tr(s):
        return s.replace('$title', 'Test')

        yaml.dump(file, sys.stdout, transform=tr)
```

Please help me. It is not necessary to work with my code, I will be happy with any examples that can suit me

Comment: So, how is your code working for you? Is there anything you need to improve?

Comment: take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61228863/transform-attribute-in-yaml-dump-is-not-working), maybe its answers may help

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so, could you let us know which ones?

Comment: @Axiumin_ no, but the file becomes completely empty after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be easier to not use the yaml package at all.

```py
with open("file.yml", "r") as fin:
     with open("file_replaced.yml", "w") as fout:
         for line in fin:
             fout.write(line.replace('$title', 'Test'))
```

EDIT:

To update in place

```py
with open("config.yml", "r+") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(contents.replace('$title', 'Test'))
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Is it possible to make changes in the file and save them to the same one, so as not to create a copy?

Comment: Edited to write in place

Answer (score 0):

You can also read & write data in one go. `os.path.join` is optional, it makes sure the `yaml` file is read relative to path your script is stored

```
import re
import os

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'temp.yaml'), 'r+') as f:
    data = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    new_data = data.replace('$title', 'replaced!')
    f.write(new_data)
    f.truncate()
```

In case you wish to dynamically replace other keywords besides `$title`, like `$description` or `$name`, you can write a function using regex like this;

```
def replaceString(text_to_search, keyword, replacement):
    return re.sub(f"(\${keyword})[\W]", replacement, text_to_search)

replaceString('My name is $name', '$name', 'Bob')
```